# In Z3, is there a way to generate undefined number of assumptions to check?

Tags: python, z3, z3py

My Python program uses Z3 Python API. It generates a number of assumptions to be checked by Z3 using the command:

```
check(P1, P2,....Pn)
```

Then I get the unsat core using the command:

```
unsat_core()
```

Is there a way I can use in my python program the command `check(P1, P2,....Pn)` without knowing the number of assertions in advance? 
The number of assumptions is defined during the run of the code and changes every run.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  You can put your assumptions into a tuple, and just use [tuple unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

eg.

```
my_assumptions = (P1, P2, ...Pn)
check(*my_assumptions)
```

Depending on how your program is structured, you may need to create/append the assumptions to a list first then convert the list to a tuple